# Cannot overwrite object?

Tags: javascript, oop, object

[RESOLVED]

Was calling the `newGame` function from an event listener so `this` would then refer to the event caller

I'm having this annoying issue with JS at the moment, I'm creating a game where all the variables for a particular game are stored in the `Game()` class/function/object and have a `GameManager` which creates the initial game and has a function to create a new one.

The problem is, I cannot overwrite the initial game in the newGame function, here it is:

```
var GameManager = {};

GameManager.currentGame = null;

GameManager.init = function() {
    this.newGame();
}

GameManager.newGame = function() {
    this.currentGame = new Game();
}

GameManager.init();
```

After running the `newGame` function, the result:

`GameManager.currentGame == the original game, NOT the new one.`

To put things in a simpler form, I've used `int`'s here:

```
var GameManager = {};

GameManager.currentGame = null;

GameManager.init = function() {
    this.currentGame = 12;
}

GameManager.newGame = function() {
    this.currentGame = 0;
}

GameManager.init();
```

After running the `newGame` function, the result:

`GameManager.currentGame == 12` (NOT 0, as expected)

I have a feeling this is an obvious issue with object referencing or something similar, I'd appreciate all responses!

Thanks

Comment: When I run it in my browser console, I get 0 for currentGame. Is there more code affecting this?

Comment: NOTE: instead of using `this` in the functions, I've used `GameManager` and it works as expected, although it would be great if I could get an explanation as to what is going on here?

Comment: You call GameManager.init(); after newGame ? It will  be always 12...

Comment: I don't think you've shown all of the key parts of code involved. Your first block of code does not behave the way you say it does; after those statements, `GameManager.currentGame` is definitely set to an object, not `null` (assuming `Game()` is a working constructor somewhere).

Comment: I ran mine in the browser as well and I got 12 like you shown, but you're only calling `GameManager.int()` when you need to be calling `GameManager.newgame()`.

Comment: Based on the information [I can't replicate the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/dgvztab7/2/)

Comment: @jlbruno thats funny, I have no idea why, I'm getting still getting 12 for currentGame, maybe there's things in my entire file setup that influence it. I run the `newGame` function from an event listener like this: `E.RESET_BTN.addEventListener("click", GameManager.newGame)`, could it be possible that `this` is referring to `E.RESET_BTN`?

Comment: *Ding Ding Ding* that's your problem. When you pass `GameManager.newGame` as an event handler like that, it loses any relationship to the `GameManager` object, and when it is called upon a "click" the value of `this` won't be what the code expects.

Comment: @DomenicCorso There you go! You're losing the context. Bind the function: `E.RESET_BTN.addEventListener("click", GameManager.newGame.bind(GameManager))`

Comment: If you're not sure, `console.log(this)` inside newGame to see what it's actually referencing. The magic of `this`.

Comment: @Pointy Sweet! Thanks all, I'm new to OOP in Javascript so I'm just trying to get my head around everything with this game project, simple question but ey was worth